# Linked List in C gives Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I've been working on implementing a command line prompt in C for linux. Basically it executes commands using system calls. All of that works so far but the next part is implementing the history command so I would typically be using a linked list command.

I get the concept of linked list and I know them but I'm hopeless at C. I can't seem to wrap my tiny pea brain around it. So each node structure will contain the command (which is an array of strings) and then the pointer to the next node.

Where am I going wrong?

Node structure definition

```
struct Node {
    char** storedCommand;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

Global Head definition

```
struct Node* head = NULL;
```

Rest of the methods

```
struct Node* createNode(char** command) {
    struct Node* returnNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    returnNode->storedCommand = command;
    returnNode->next = NULL;
    return returnNode;
}

void addNode(char** command) {
    struct Node* tempNode = createNode(command);

    if(head == NULL) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        head = tempNode;
    } else {
        struct Node* pointerNode = head;

        while(pointerNode->next != NULL) {
            pointerNode = pointerNode->next;
        }

        pointerNode->next = tempNode;
    }
}

void traverseList() {
    struct Node* p = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    p = head;
    printf("%s", head->storedCommand[0]); // This line fails but why; I thought I have already defined head
    while(p != NULL) {
        printf("%s", p->storedCommand[0]);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

So I put a comment where it is faulting at but I really don't know why.

Here is my main

```
int main() {

    while(TRUE) {
        printPrompt();
        cmdLine = readCommandLine();
        cmd = parseCommandLine(cmdLine);

        if(strcmp(cmd[0], "history") != 0) {
            addNode(cmd);
        }

        if(isInternalCommand(cmd)) {
            executeInternalCommand(cmd);
        } else {
            pid = fork();

            if(pid == 0) {
                executeCommand(cmd);
            } else if(pid > 0){
                child = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            } else {
                printf("There was an error\n");
            }
        }

        free(cmdLine);
        int walk = 0;
        while(cmd[walk] != NULL) {
            free(cmd[walk]);
            walk++;
        }
        free(cmd);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

This is what calls the traverselist function

```
/**
 * Executes the given internal command; Nothing is returned since this is all executed on the address space
 * @param cmd The command to be executed
 */
void executeInternalCommand(char** cmd) {
    if(strcmp(cmd[0], "exit") == 0) {
        exit(0);
    } else if(strcmp(cmd[0], "cd") == 0) {
        if(cmd[1] != NULL) {
            chdir(cmd[1]);
        }
    } else if(strcmp(cmd[0], "echo") == 0) {
        int temp_index = 1;
        while(cmd[temp_index] != NULL) {
            if(cmd[temp_index + 1] != NULL) {
                snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "%s ", cmd[temp_index]);
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            } else if(cmd[temp_index] != NULL && cmd[temp_index + 1] == NULL) {
                snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "%s\n", cmd[temp_index]);
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            } else {
                snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "\n");
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            }
            temp_index++;
        }
    } else if(strcmp(cmd[0], "help") == 0) {
        if(cmd[1] == NULL) {
            snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)\n");
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "These shell commands are defined internally. 'Type help' to see this list.\n");
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "Type 'help name' to find out more about the function 'name'.\n\n");
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "%-30s %-30s\n", "cd [File Path]", "help name");
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "%-30s %-30s\n", "echo [Text]", "exit");
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
        } else {
            if(strcmp(cmd[1], "exit") == 0) {
                snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "exit\nExits the program with status code 0\n");
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            } else if(strcmp(cmd[1], "cd") == 0) {
                snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "cd [File Path]\nChange the current directory. Accepts argument 'File Path' to change the present working directory to the 'File Path'\n");
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            } else if(strcmp(cmd[1], "echo") == 0) {
                snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "echo [Text]\nPrints [Text] to the screen\n");
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            } else {
                snprintf(message, WRITE_BUFFER, "The help page for this command is currently not supported\n");
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
            }
        }
    } else if(*cmd[0] == '!') {
        printf("Banger!!!!\n");
    } else if(strcmp(cmd[0], "history") == 0) {
        printf("History command\n");
        traverseList();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I had a very rookie mistake. In my `addNode` function I allocated space in there for my `returnNode` AND returning that. So when I return a local variable from a function and try to use it outside of the method scope I will obviously have messed up memory references. Just a big rookie mistake there messing up with scopes.

Comment: What's your `main` for a [mcve]? Have you tried running this in a debugger?

Comment: For the sake of keeping it short I'm leaving out all of the other methods that aren't applicable to the question. I've tried to give the debugger a shot but I really had a hard time figuring it out for C

Comment: Your `main` function doesn't even invoke your linked list code.  What do you want us to debug?

Comment: It calls ```addNode``` when the command that is inputted is not history. I updated to include a function that is relevant when the ```history``` command is called

Comment: If you have a global `struct Node* head;` you may as well have a global `struct Node* tail;` to allow O(1) in-order insertion. In `add()` it simply becomes `if(head == NULL) { ... head = tail = tempNode;` and the `else` portion is then `tail->next = tempNode; tail = tempNode;`  period -- no iteration. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 10 lines of sample data so we can help with the rest. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Tip: Don't be so self-deprecating. Sometimes learning a programming language involves not being smart, but dumbing yourself down to the language, and C in particular is a really *dumb* language. If you're used to others like Python that do tons of things for you, C doesn't do anything, so you must think in very, very basic terms.

Comment: The debugger is an essential tool here. If it crashes in a predictable location that's great, you can always work up from there. Find out where the fault is. Set a breakpoint a little bit before that execution point and *carefully* observe all values being used.

Comment: Using GDB I figured out that I was accessing invalid memory when I was printing out ```storedCommand[0]``` so instead of using a ```char**``` in my data structure I am going to use ```char*``` to print out a string. A little more work but not too bad. As for David suggesting a tail I didn't add this as this is all prototype but also its for a class where I don't need it to be perfectly optimized. If I did I would otherwise

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the root cause of your crash, but this is a bug. You are leaking an object here in your `addnode` function:

```
void addNode(char** command) {
    struct Node* tempNode = createNode(command);

    if(head == NULL) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        head = tempNode;
    }
```

Should be:

```
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = tempNode;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I did catch that earlier but forgot to take it haha I was trying to see what would work